# Jump to the next item on a collection upon click event

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a collection of items that I use with an `interval` like bellow:

```java
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .zipWith(Observable.interval(3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (item, interval) -> item) 
  .subscribe()
```

The current flow is that each item is displayed for 3500 ms.
What I want to achieve is to jump to the next item if the user clicks on a button before reaching 3500 ms.

I tried to achieve that through a `Subject` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you could use an `amb()` to combine a timer with a user click. The `amb()` will emit either the timer tick or the user click depending on which is triggered first. And then, you could use a `repeat()` to get the recurring execution.
Below, a user click is "simulated" while the timer has been set to 5 seconds (instead of the 3500 ms to check the sample):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Random random = new Random();
    final Observable<String> userClick =
            Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(random.nextInt(8)))
                                             .flatMap(t -> Observable.timer(t, SECONDS).map(__ -> (long) t))
                                             .map(t -> String.format("user click after %d seconds", t));

    final Observable<String> timer = Observable.timer(5, SECONDS)
                                               .map(__ -> "tick after 5 seconds!");

    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
              .zipWith(Observable.ambArray(timer, userClick)
                                 .doOnNext(s -> System.out.printf("%s\n", s))
                                 .repeat(),
                       (item, tick) -> item)
              .subscribe(System.out::println,
                         System.err::println,
                         () -> System.out.println("End!"));

    Flowable.timer(1, MINUTES) // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

If you run the program, you can have this kind of result:

```
tick after 5 seconds!
1
user click after 3 seconds
2
tick after 5 seconds!
3
user click after 0 seconds
4
user click after 1 seconds
5
End!
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I played many hours with `ambArray` and seemd to only took the source that emit the first time as the fault one.

For example : `ambArray(source1, source2, source3).repeat()` if the `source1` is the faster one after subscription it will always be the default in contrast *source2* and *source3* will be ignored. IMO this is what the `amb` doc highlight : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html

Comment: That's what `amb()` does indeed. The `repeat()` is here to allow the choice between a user click and a tick every time a new item is emitted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what did work for me (`takeUntil` operator *condition*) :

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .zipWith(
            intervalRange()
                .doOnNext {
                    onEachIntervalEmit(it)
                }
                .takeUntil(buttonUneStream)
                .takeUntil(buttonUnStream)
                .repeat()
```

A lill details about `intervalRang` definition :

```
private fun intervalRange(): Flowable<Long> {
    return Flowable.intervalRange(
        0,
        10,
        0,
        4,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
    )
}
```

I do like `intervalRange` because it allow to specify the initial delay.